# Why does a single node cluster only have a small percentage of the cpu quota available?

Tags: kubernetes

[pod will not start due to "No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573825/pod-will-not-start-due-to-no-nodes-are-available-that-match-all-of-the-followin/45585916#45585916)

In the above question, I had an issue starting a deployment with 3 containers.

Upon further investigation, it appears there is only 27% of the CPU quota available - which seems very low. The rest of the CPU seems to be assigned to some default bundled containers.

How is this normally mitigated? Is a larger node required? Do limits need to be set manually? Are all those additional containers necessary?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33777

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391748/how-to-reduce-cpu-limits-of-kubernetes-system-resources

Answer (score 3):

1 cpu for a single node cluster is probably too small.

From the containers in the original answer, both the dashboard and fluentd can be removed:

- the dashboard is just a web UI, which can go away if you use `kubectl` (which you should, IMO);
- fluentd should be reading the log files on disk to ship them somewhere (GCP's log aggregation, I think).

The unnecessary containers should be tied to a `Deployment` or `ReplicaSet`, which can be listed with `kubectl get deployment` and `kubectl get rs`, respectively. You can then `kubectl delete` them.

Increasing the resources on the node should not change the requirements for the basic pods, meaning they should all be free scheduling.

Comment: How would I remove the unnecessary containers? With a larger node / more cpus - do the limits for these bundled containers go lower?

Comment: From my understanding, it's a single replica. Just 3 containers being run.