# How do I remove the Kubernetes dashboard resources from my deployment on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I've created a Kubernetes deployment. However, there seem to be additional  pods running - that I'm hoping to be able to delete the unnecessary ones.

I see no need to run the dashboard container. I'd like to remove it to free up CPU resources.

How can I disable this container from starting up? Preferably from the deployment config.

Essentially the following pod:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep "dashboard"                                  
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-490794276-sb6qs                  1/1       Running   1          3d
```

**Additional information:**

Output of `kubectl --namespace kube-system get deployment`:

```
NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
heapster-v1.3.0        1         1         1            1           3d
kube-dns               2         2         2            2           3d
kube-dns-autoscaler    1         1         1            1           3d
kubernetes-dashboard   1         1         1            1           11m
l7-default-backend     1         1         1            1           3d
```

Output of `kubectl --namespace kube-system get rs`:

```
NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
heapster-v1.3.0-191291410        1         1         1         3d
heapster-v1.3.0-3272732411       0         0         0         3d
heapster-v1.3.0-3742215525       0         0         0         3d
kube-dns-1829567597              2         2         2         3d
kube-dns-autoscaler-2501648610   1         1         1         3d
kubernetes-dashboard-490794276   1         1         1         12m
l7-default-backend-3574702981    1         1         1         3d
```

Answer (score 69):

### Update 2023-03

To have a clean removal you must delete a lot of objects. Overtime removing the dashboard has been a common problem, so you can now do this:

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

If you don't want to do a blind thing and you want to know what are you removing just try to execute this:

```
kubectl get secret,sa,role,rolebinding,services,deployments --namespace=kube-system | grep dashboard
```

If the output is empty, just double check your dashboard namespace's with the command

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

The dashboard is stored in a separate namespace and, depending of your context, the dashboard can be not always in the same namespace. If you want have a deeper look start trying with `kubernetes-dashboard` or `kube-system` and always specify the namespace while callin `kubectl`.

Comment: should be flag as the accepted answer.

Comment: kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml 404

Comment: @geekyouth thanks for checking, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 35):

**UPDATE MAY 2020:**

Thanks to [Lee Richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40783/lee-richardson) for his comment ;)

They have changed the organisation of the files in the repo and as well the command on [Kubernetes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui), so the new `kubectl delete` command needs to be:

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

As said before, you can delete the deployment to remove the pods too, running this:

```
kubectl delete deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
```

But, **if you want to clean all the dashboard related things**, you can simply execute the delete command K8s cluster file based in the official [Kubernetes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui):

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Comment: the first two answers are misleading since I have tabulated errors to remove the bad service, Thank you for your response, it will help me :D

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml is 404.  Maybe this needs to be replaced with the individual files that have taken it's place at: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/aio/deploy/recommended

Answer (score 28):

None of these answers worked for me because every answer assumes the namespace is `kube-system`, which is not always true.
Thus, you need to first see the names space:

```
$ kubectl get deployments -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default                nginx-deployment            3/3     3            3           39m
kube-system            coredns                     2/2     2            2           93m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           12m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           12m
```

You can see from the first column (NAMESPACE), then:

```
$ kubectl delete deployment kubernetes-dashboard  --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
$ kubectl delete deployment dashboard-metrics-scraper --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Do the same for services (if any):

```
$kubectl get service -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                  102m
default                nginx-service               NodePort    10.96.31.151   <none>        80:31634/TCP             49m
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   102m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.102.22.35   <none>        8000/TCP                 22m
```

Then delete any dashboard services:

```
$ kubectl delete service kubernetes-dashboard  --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
$ kubectl delete service dashboard-metrics-scraper  --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Then finally the service account and secrets:

```
$ kubectl delete sa kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
$ kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-certs --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
$ kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: This is the real answer, and the only one that will work if you followed the kubernetes documentation which has you install the dashboard in the kubernetes-dashboard namespace not kube-system

Answer (score 13):

Simply go with `kubectl --namespace kube-system delete deployment kubernetes-dashboard` and you'll have no more dashboard in your cluster

Comment: When would I need to run this command? Would once be sufficient to prevent it from starting up again in future?

Comment: It seems to start right back up after being deleted.

Comment: did you run exactly the command I provided ? if so, please provide output of `kubectl --namespace kube-system get deployment` and `kubectl --namespace kube-system get rs`

Comment: how did you provision the cluster?

Comment: sidenote: does it really bother you that you have dashboard running at all ? this particular component has near zero footprint

Comment: This is on google could platfrom. So ` gcloud container clusters create wordpress --num-nodes=2`

Comment: Right... I don't think you'll be able to get rid of it then -_-

Comment: Regarding the reason for needing it removed. It's preventing my container from starting up. As it seems the CPU allocation is very limited. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586069/why-does-a-single-node-cluster-only-have-a-small-percentage-of-the-cpu-quota-ava

Answer (score 13):

Using a label selector:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system delete deployment,service,role,rolebinding,sa,secret -l k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit deployment kubernetes-dashboard
```

And set `replicas: 0`

This seems to work for the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For me the most easy way to do it, is to find with which yaml you deploy it.
and simply do :

kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc7/aio/deploy/alternative.yaml

replace with your yaml.
This the best way to clean up because what you deployed will be delete.

Answer (score 0):

### Update December 2020:

`kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`

You can also have a look this link: [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui) and replace the "apply" with "delete" on the deployment command.

Comment: You didn't add the link!

Comment: Thanks @OctaveL the link has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Just click "Delete" when selecting the dashboard under the namespaces using the [vs code kubernetes extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools).

[image]

You will be asked to confirm the deletion after that. This happens on the right side of your screen.

[image]

Then it will ask you if you really want to delete all the underlying resources.
[image]

In this way you see what you are doing without the need of the command-line.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the `Deployment`, all the related pods will be terminated automatically.

Comment: I want to keep the other containers in the deployment running.

Comment: you have a single deployment that servers the dashboard and other things?

Comment: Have updated the question - sorry for the confusion it's actually a pod not a container.

Comment: Ok, thats a pod. Did you start this pod manually? Or using a Deployment? ReplicationController? ReplicaSet?

Comment: It's a default pod started/managed by kubernetes as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you explain a little your environment?

Answer (score -1):

```
kubectl delete ([-f FILENAME] | TYPE [(NAME | -l label | --all)])
```

https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_delete/

Answer (score -1):

I use "minikube start" create.Then use "minikube dashboard" create the dashboard.Finally,I use "minikube config set dashboard false" to stop and delete the dashboard resources(including service,deployment,...).

Answer (score -2):

'minikube addons disable dashboard' worked for me. Using v1.6.2.